# How to change the names of lists using lapply and map in R

Tags: r, lapply, purrr

I would like the names/column names of two data frames to match after binding the respective lists. I am first obtaining the number of housing units for the state.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidycensus)

nc <- lapply(2010:2019, function(x) get_acs(geography = "state", state = "NC", table = "B25001", survey = "acs1",
                                         year = x, moe_level = 95, cache_table = TRUE) %>% mutate(year = x))
```

Then, I do the same process for each county in North Carolina.

```
counties <- fips_codes %>% 
filter(state == "NC") %>% 
mutate(county = str_replace(county, " County", "")) %>% 
select(county)
county <- map(2010:2019, ~ lapply(counties, function(x) get_acs(geography = "county", state = "NC", 
                                                                         county = x, table = "B25001", survey = "acs5",
                                                                         year = .x, moe_level = 95, cache_table = TRUE) %>% mutate(year = .x)))
```

Next, I bind the lists together.

```
nc_data <- bind_rows(nc)
county_data <- bind_rows(county)

names(county_data)
names(nc_data)
```

My issue is the names/column names of the `county_data` object is just "county". I would like the `county_data` object's names to match the names of the `nc_data` object. During my use of `map` and `lapply`, how can I manipulate the names of the `county` object to match the `nc` object?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a sample dataset using `dput(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the desired result using `unnest()` on `county`:

```
> county_data <- county_data %>% unnest(county)
> names(county_data)
[1] "GEOID"    "NAME"     "variable" "estimate" "moe"      "year"    
> names(nc_data)
[1] "GEOID"    "NAME"     "variable" "estimate" "moe"      "year"
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, and great idea!